# How can i get the values in eloquent relation array result of laravel 8

Tags: multidimensional-array, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship, php-7.4

I have a result array from laravel8 relations. like below

```
$val = {
         "q_id": 1,
         "q_text": "1111",
         "q_mandatory": 1,
         "q_status": "unpublished",
         "que_logic_relation": [
         {
           "ql_id": 1,
           "ql_quest_id": 1,
           "ql_answer_choice_id": null,
           "ql_succeeding_q_order": 3,

         },
         {
           "ql_id": 4,
           "ql_quest_id": 1,
           "ql_answer_choice_id": null,
           "ql_succeeding_q_order": 3,
       
         }
  
       ]
   }
```

When I print $val['q_text'] // output 1111
when I print $val['que_logic_relation']  //no result or empty
I want to print the data in que_logic_relation seperately. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not a valid php code, you mean your value is json? If so, use `$val = json_decode($resultArray,true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issued fixed by adding toArray() to the query result and everything works fine now.